# A question about add element at the end of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I tried to write a program to add some nodes in a linked list.
When I compile and run it, I get a segmentation fault.
Could anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};                          // define a structure

struct node* first;         //the first node;

void insert(int n)          // function to insert element at the end
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* ptr = first;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->link = NULL;
    while(ptr->link != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    ptr->link = temp;
}

void Print()                //function to print out the element
{
    struct node* ptr = first;
    printf("List is:");
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i,k,n;
    first = NULL;
    printf("How many numbers you want to insert?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter:");
        scanf("%d",&k);
        insert(k);
    }
    Print(); //Print out the linked list
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regarding _the compiler gives me a segmentation fault_, the compiler is capable of providing a warning that a variable may be uninitialized before being accessed, a segmentation fault is a run-time phenomena,  and occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed (for example, attempting to write to a read-only location, or to overwrite part of the operating system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attempt to insert the first element in the list, `first` is `NULL` which means you set `ptr` to `NULL`.  Then when you check `ptr->link != NULL` at the start of the loop you dereference a `NULL` pointer which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Before attempting to traverse the list, check if `first` is `NULL` and if so set it to the new node and return.

```
void insert(int n)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* ptr = first;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->link = NULL;

    if (!first) {
        first = temp;
        return;
    }
    while(ptr->link != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    ptr->link = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the following section, `ptr` is being assigned to `first`, which is initialized to `null`:

```
struct node* first;         //the first node;

void insert(int n)          // function to insert element at the end
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* ptr = first;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->link = NULL;
    while(ptr->link != NULL)
           |_____Dereference of null pointer occurs here.
    ...
```

In this section, Test `first`, and if `null` assign it to `temp` and return.

But your question is really asking how to *'add element to the end of a linked list'*, (which I am interpreting as *'appending a new node to the end of a linked list'*.)  If that interpretation is correct, then the function doing that requires knowing something about the existing list.  The prototype of your existing function includes only data, but needs to also include a reference to the existing list.  The following uses the name *append*, to more accurately what I believe you want to do, and includes both a reference to the existing list, and the data.

void append(struct node** head_ref, int new_data);//(int n in your code)

In designing a function to do this, the following ideas should be included:

- Create a new node  `new_node`
- Create a pointer to last node
- assign input value `new_data` to new_node->data
- initialize new_node->next to `NULL`
- test head reference to see if list is empty, if so set new_node to head
- if not empty, loop through until end of list
- assign last->next to point to new_node

Example implementation:

```
void append(struct node** head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
    struct node *last = *head_ref;  
    new_node->data  = new_data; 
    new_node->link = NULL; 
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
       *head_ref = new_node; 
       return; 
    } 
    while (last->link != NULL) 
        last = last->link; 
    last->link = new_node; 
    return; 
}
```

This implementation accommodates a series of calls to *append* to a list, whether its the very first list item, or to a list that is already populated.

A simple calling example - with a graphic showing what its results look like in memory:

```
int main(void)
{  
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {  
        append(&first, i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `first` is also initialized to `0` because it's global.

Answer (score 3):

Your node `first` is declared to be a pointer and later set to NULL. Just turn your first-node into a value ( or malloc space for it ).

Answer (score 1):

When you first call `insert`, `first` is `NULL`.  The following is your problem:

```
void insert(int n)          // function to insert element at the end
{
    ...
    struct node* ptr = first;
    ...
    while(ptr->link != NULL)
    ...
}
```

You're dereferencing `ptr` which is `NULL`.  Add an `if` check in `insert` to see if `ptr` is `NULL`.  Something like this:

```
if(ptr == NULL)
{
    first = tmp;
}
else
{
    while(ptr->link != NULL)
        ptr = ptr->link;
    ptr->link = temp;
}
```

You should have a similar check in `Print`.